# Comparing datetime64[ns] colmns in a pandas dataframe in lambda seems to be not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What i want to acheive is to change date-time value in Dt-1 with Dt-2 if Dt-1 is grater than Dt-2.
I am using lambda function with if-else pattern to compare colums but, Dt-1 value is changed if the condition is not met. Any help is appriciated.Thank you.

Bellow is my short code sample , and output when run :

```
     import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "2022-11-01 00:01:11", "2022-11-02 00:02:33"]
                   ],
                  columns=["gr", "Dt-1", "Dt-2"])

df["Dt-1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dt-1"])
df["Dt-2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dt-2"])

print(df)
print(df.info())

df["Dt-1"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Dt-1"] if x["Dt-1"] >
                      x["Dt-2"] else x["Dt-2"], axis=1)

print(df)
print(df.info())
```

[image: Program output:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code

```
df["Dt-1"] = df[['Dt-1', 'Dt-2']].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it is much more clean and practical.
May I ask for some further help if possible? I have difficulty on applying your solution when dataframe is grouped on "gr". I mean , when i use 

df["Dt-1"] = df.groupby("gr")[['Dt-1', 'Dt-2']].max()

i get  ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Why is groupby needed to compare two columns? Make examples needed groupby

Comment: The real dataframe i am working on is is a GPS data for all company cars , so i need to process each cars data individually by grouping.

very simple sample
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "2022-11-01 00:02:33", "2022-11-01 00:01:11"],
                   ["a", "2022-11-02 00:00:33", "2022-11-02 00:01:44"],
                   ["b", "2022-11-02 00:02:13", "2022-11-04 00:02:01"],
                   ["c", "2022-11-02 00:00:33", "2022-11-02 00:03:11"],
                   ["c", "2022-11-02 00:08:33", "2022-11-02 00:06:11"],
                   ],
                  columns=["gr", "Dt-1", "Dt-2"])

Comment: comparing two columns is not necessary groupby. You're trying to use groupby where groupby isn't needed. don need groupby in your example

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this , if-else works correct... my bad sorry...   :)

```
lambda x: x["Dt-1"] if x["Dt-1"] > x["Dt-2"] else x["Dt-2"]
```